# What is the better way to extract text from content in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to know the best way to query and extract text from an oracle database.

I have this query:

```sql
SELECT
    navigation_url 
FROM
    content_i18n 
    LEFT JOIN
        content 
        ON content_i18n_content_id = content_id 
    LEFT JOIN
        navigation 
        ON content_navigation_id = navigation_id 
WHERE
    content_i18n_text LIKE '%### PHP%' 
    OR content_i18n_extra_text LIKE '%### PHP%' 
    OR content_i18n_custom_slider LIKE '%### PHP%' 
    OR content_i18n_home_slider LIKE '%### PHP%' 
    OR content_i18n_js LIKE '%### PHP%' 
    OR content_i18n_see_also LIKE '%### PHP%'
```

This query returns me the navigation URL, but I would like to get also the piece of text between `### PHP` and `###` (the 3 # (`###`) is used both to open and close the PHP content). And if it is possible, the field where it appears (`content_i18n_text`, `content_i18n_extra_text`, etc).

The example bellow is from the field `content_i18n_text` but also it could be from every field of the where clause.

```
"(CLOB) 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6 ">

                ### PHP echo insertar_video_youtube('5joUgy6doRo'); ###
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p><strong>Text bold</strong>. This is an example .</p>
            </div>
            ### PHP another_funcion_in_php(...)
            $hello = 4
            echo "Hello!"
            ###
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
"
```

I would like to get a column with the navigation_url (already works), and another column with the code between '### PHP' and '###' which name could be the field where it appears (`content_i18n_text`). In the example, I have 2 matches of the expression, How could I handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`regexp_replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions163.htm#SQLRF06302):

```
select regexp_replace(navigation_url, '^.*### PHP(.*)###.*$', '\1')
```

Comment: Hi! I just provide sample data and desired results. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` function,

```
select replace(navigation_url, '#', '') as navigation_url from content_i18n 
left join content on content_i18n_content_id = content_id
left join navigation on content_navigation_id = navigation_id
where content_i18n_text like '%### PHP%' 
or content_i18n_extra_text like '%### PHP%'
or content_i18n_custom_slider like '%### PHP%'
or content_i18n_home_slider like '%### PHP%'
or content_i18n_js like '%### PHP%'
or content_i18n_see_also like '%### PHP%';
```